# Load drawable from URL into memory and get the resource id

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable, picasso, photoeditorsdk

I'm current using PhotoEditorSDK, its method to load sticker take in drawable (https://www.photoeditorsdk.com/documentation/android/customization#adding-or-removing-stickers), but now I want to load the stickers from a URL.

My theory is to first load the URL into Bitmap (I'm using Picasso), and then convert the Bitmap into Drawable.

But I'm not able to get the resource id of the drawable, any advise?

Below is part of the code I'm trying so far.

```
Target target = new Target() {
      @Override
      public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
           Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
      }

      @Override
      public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
      }
}

Picasso.with(this).load("http://example.com/image.png").into(target);
```

How do I get the resource id with Drawable `d` ?

Comment: Do you mind using Glide instead of Picasso?, i can can write that for you

Comment: THis should work as is.  Why do you think you need a resource id?  Not all drawables have them, and they don't need them.  If they only provide an API that uses resource ids, then you have to have the images in your drawables folder, you can't download them.

Comment: what resource id are you talking about?

Comment: @HtmlTosin yea I don't mind using other library, I'm still test stuff around :)

Comment: @GabeSechan yea I know I need to have them in the drawable folder, but what I'm trying to do now is to load the drawable from URL into memory, give it a resource id and refer it, as I mentioned in my post it's a theory to do it, I'm not sure if it's possible

Comment: @njzk2 as mentioned in the PhotoEditor's documentation, `Drawable resource identifier of the icon (String)`

Comment: @MiloKhoo sorry, you can't resources like that, with a resource id, are only those created at compile time. You cannot create new resources at runtime.